# AngularJS set localstorage (object json)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

How can I change/modify/refresh my `localstorage` of AngularJS?

My `localstorage` content is an `object` json:

```
//data content: {Id:1,Name:"Juanito"}
localStorageService.set("MyObj",data);

console.log(localStorageService.get("MyObj"));
//SHOW object JSON {Id:1,Name:"Juanito"}
```

But if I modify a unique key like this:

```
localStorageService.set("MyObj.Id","otherid"),
```

It does not work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try retrieving, then updating and re-setting:

```
var data = {id: 123}
localStorageService.set("MyObj",data);
var dataFromLS = localStorageService.get("MyObj");
dataFromLS.id = 456;
localStorageService.set("MyObj",data);
console.log(localStorageService.get("MyObj"));
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your response!
I thought set direct localstorage... but your response is simple and i helped, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. When you change/modify your key name, a brand new object will be created/stored in your service.
2. If you want to change/alter key's data/value, perform intermediate operations and set it with same key.